# Add Carriage Return to NSString

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ascii

I've made an app which sends data to an SQL database. The data is send trough an UITextView which has multiple lines.

Normally Windows sees an enter(line break) as the Hexadecimal 0D0A.
0D = Carriage Return
0A = Line Feed

Now the app only sends the 0A hexadecimal Line feed. Not the 0D carriage return. How do I get the 0A (line feed) replaced by 0D0A(carriage return, line feed)?

Comment: Is that app in Objective-C or C#? Please remove the irrelevant tag.

Comment: Are you using C# and .NET, or Objective C on the iPad?  It seems unlikely you're doing both.

Comment: I'm using objective c to write the app. But I use C# & .NET to insert the data into my MsSQL database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it in my C# .NET enviroment.

```
string.Replace("\n", Enviroment.NewLine);
```

Answer (score 5):

Wherever you send your data to the SQL database, assign the contents of the UITextView to a NSMutableString and then replace any line feeds with CRLF's.  You can then forward the NSMutableString to your database.

E.G.

```
NSMutableString * stringToSend = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString: yourTextView.text];
if(stringToSend)
{
    [stringToSend replaceOccurencesOfString: @"\r" withString: @"\r\n" options: NSBackwardsSearch range: NSMakeRange(0, [stringToSend length])];
    //  now you can send this string to your database
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Michael! I'm gonna try it out.

Comment: Hmm.. That doesn't seem to work. I wrote the exact code as you did. But I still only got a line feed in my MsSQL database.

Comment: The code `replaceOccurencesOfString: @"\r"` should be `replaceOccurencesOfString: @"\n"`. \r = CR and \n = LF.